# Error with looped matrix "arguments imply differing number of rows"

Tags: r, loops, matrix, error-handling

I have a dataset including monthly ndvi and precipitation data for three land cover types with a total of 26 stations for 13 years each. I would like to run a loop to fill in the matrix m1 with "ndvi" and "cv" for each year per station per land cover type. In the end I need three plots of the three looped land cover matrices.

I'm running into an error when I enter the script shown below. I'm not sure why there is a "differing number of rows", since there is always one max ndvi value and one cv value per year per station. Can someone maybe offer an advice on what my mistake might be? This script worked for my analyses with mean ndvi, but somehow with max it doesn't.

```
dput(head(d))

structure(list(row.names = c(1L, 1769L, 2055L, 2341L, 2627L, 
2913L), timestamp = 1:6, station = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("Aiselukharka", "Anarmani", "BiratnagarAirport", 
"Chainpur", "Chandragadhi", "Damak", "Dhankuta", "Diktel", "Dingla", 
"Haraicha", "Ilam", "Kanyam", "Kechana", "KhotangBazar", "Leguwa", 
"Letang", "ManebhanjyangBazar", "Muga", "Mulghat", "Num", "Okhaldunga", 
"PakhribasBazar", "Phidim", "Sanischare", "Sankhuwasabha", "Tumlingtar"
), class = "factor"), year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L), month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L), .Label = c("apr", 
"aug", "dec", "feb", "jan", "jul", "jun", "mar", "may", "nov", 
"oct", "sept"), class = "factor"), ndvi = c(0.4138, 0.4396, 0.4393, 
0.6029, 0.4756, 0.4969), landcover = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Cropland/Natural vegetation mosaic", 
"Croplands", "Mixed forest"), class = "factor"), altitude = c(2143L, 
2143L, 2143L, 2143L, 2143L, 2143L), altrange = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0-500", "1501-2000", "2001+", 
"501-1500"), class = "factor"), precipitation = c(16, 4, 25.5, 
72.6, 241.7, 505.9)), .Names = c("row.names", "timestamp", "station", 
"year", "month", "ndvi", "landcover", "altitude", "altrange", 
"precipitation"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

d <- read.csv("asort.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
stations <- levels(d$station)
landcover <- levels(d$landcover)
allyears=c$year[ ! duplicated( c$year)]

for(lc in landcover) {
m1=NULL
for(j in stations){
  for (i in allyears){
      tmp <- d[d$landcover==lc & d$station==j & d$year==i,]
      ndvi<- tmp$ndvi[which.max(tmp$ndvi)];  
      precip_2m<-tmp$precipitation[tmp$month %in% c("feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug")]
      cv<-sd(precip_2m,na.rm=T)/mean(precip_2m, na.rm=T)
      station=j
      landcover=lc
      year=i
      lag=l
      m1 = rbind(m1, data.frame(ndvi, cv,landcover, station, year))
  }
}
 cat("landcover=",lc) 
 print(summary(aov(ndvi~cv,data=m1)))
 plot(ndvi~cv,main=lc,
     xlab="cv of growing season precipitation", ylab="max ndvi ", data=m1)
 abline(lm(ndvi~cv, data=m1))
 fit = summary(lm(ndvi~cv, data=m1))
 r2 = fit$adj.r.squared  
 my.p = fit$coefficients[2,4]
 rp = vector('expression',2)
 rp[1] = substitute(expression(italic(R)^2 == value.r), list(value.r = format(r2,dig=3)))[2]                  
 rp[2] = substitute(expression(italic(p) == value.p), list(value.p = format(my.p, digits = 2))[2]                  
legend('topright', legend = rp, bty = 'n')
}


Error in data.frame(ndvi, cv, landcover, station, year) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide some sample data to run your code with, preferably by adding a `dput` of your data to your question.

Comment: @beginneR hi, i added a few rows of my dataset to show what it looks like. each of the 26 stations have 13 years of monthly data. each station is either "mixed forest", "cropland" or "cropland/natural vegetation mosaic".

Comment: Thanks, but could you replace the data you just added with the output of `dput(head(yourdata))` because it can then be copied easily? The format is otherwise not correct when I copy your sample data from above

Comment: Are you (mis)-using `attach`? The code makes me think you are under the impression that the column names are available as objects. (They are not.)

Comment: @beginneR please see the edited sample data! thanks

Comment: @BondedDust i just included the column names in the m1 to have an overview of what gets put into the matrix, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @user3460660 thanks. are you using a number of variables which are not part of your data.frame but have the same names as some of the columns? `landcover` is one example for that. `stations` (note the s) is another variable that is not from your data.frame. So the problem is I cant reproduce your error and hence it's difficult to figure out the problem and how it could be resolved. You should include all relevant data in your question to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: No. The index vectors are named 'landcover' and 'stations' and those entities do not exist as first class objects.

Comment: @beginneR yes sorry i used similar names for the variables. please see the edited script. thanks for your patience!! i hope it works now.

Comment: @user3460660 `allyears=c$year[ ! duplicated( c$year)]` seems to come from another data.frame `c` which is not available (or did you mean data.frame `d`?

Comment: i cant reproduce the error, but it may well be that it comes from one of the loops having a larger index than in your data.frame, so check that out. Also, by using `landcover <- levels(d$landcover)` you may get more levels than are visible in your data.frame. so try to `d$landcover <- droplevels(d$landcover))` before getting the levels. Last but not least, you may consider optimizing your code by avoiding (triple!) for loops.

Comment: @beginneR please replace "c" with "d"

Comment: @beginneR thing is, the code works with using mean ndvi instead of max. ndvi<-mean(tmp$ndvi[tmp$month %in% c("feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug")]) i don't know why it's having an issue when using max:(

Comment: @user3460660 in your example you are not using `max` but `which.max` and that is a different function. Try `max` where `mean` worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that error when there are no values in a particular subset (`nrow(tmp)==0`). The difference between `mean` and what you're doing now is that `mean(NULL)` actually returned a vector of length 1 where as `tmp$ndvi[which.max(tmp$ndvi)]` will return a zero-length vector. This is the mismatch between the values you are specifically assigning (like station, landcover, etc) which will always have a length 1, and the values you are calculating which can be zero-length hence the mismatch error.

So you could do two things. The easiest is to replace

```
ndvi<- tmp$ndvi[which.max(tmp$ndvi)];
```

with

```
ndvi<- max(tmp$ndvi);
```

because `max` has the same behavior as `mean` in so far as it will return something. But of course that means you're just getting bizarre data in your final result. Alternative you could test for empty `tmp` data.fames with

```
for (i in allyears){
    tmp <- d[d$landcover==lc & d$station==j & d$year==i,]
    if(nrow(tmp)>0) {
       ...
       m1 = rbind(m1, data.frame(ndvi, cv,landcover, station, year))
    }
}
```

But really is seems like you should be able to use `aggregate` to calculate most of these values (though you may have to call it more than once for different summary functions).

Comment: thanks a lot!! both options work, although i'm not sure what you mean by getting bizarre data?